# Efficient JSON parser for Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, import, parsing, json-format

Im looking for a efficient way of parsing JSON data in *Mathematica*. I am having a lot of problems with `ImportString` because it uses Java, is too slow, and uses too much memory (and, also, sometimes it just returns Null).

Do you know how to write a function for JSON parsing in *Mathematica*, or how to use any C/C++ (or other efficient) library from *Mathematica*?

Comment: You can see if the alternative at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633003/parsing-and-generating-json might be faster.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica did you use to try to import JSON?  Mathematica 10 has an all-new JSON importer that fixes many problems version 9 had.

Answer (score 9):

Recent versions of Mathematica no longer use Java for parsing JSON, and work very fast.

There are at least three ways to read JSON.

- `Import[..., "JSON"]` is fast an reliable. It returns nested `List`s and `Rule`s.
- `Import[..., "RawJSON"]` is faster than `"JSON"` and returns nested `List`s and `Association`s.  These are much easier to work with than `Rule`s.
- The `` Developer` `` context has JSON reading and writing functions.  There are functions for reading from files, streams or strings.  There are functions for encoding/decoding Mathematica expressions (labelled `Expression`) and functions for reading/writing arbitrary JSON (labelled as `Raw`). These latter ones are essentially equivalent to `Import[..., "RawJSON"]`.

  Example:  `` Developer`ReadRawJSONString[str] ``

  These functions have much lower overhead than `Import`/`Export` because they do not have to invoke the entire [import framework](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html).  In fact they are so fast that [in *some* cases using them for data transfer with LibraryLink can be faster than using MathLink](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/575100).

Answer (score 2):

Longtime user, first time responder.

I am going to assume that by parsing you mean extracting values from JSON data and not transforming data into JSON.

There are a couple ways to parse JSON in Mathematica. Assuming the data is already a set of rules in Mathematica using `Import[data, "JSON"]` or something like that.

```
data = {blah -> blah, field1 -> var, field2 -> var2, blah-> blah, ...}
```

The first is `Cases`

```
Cases[data,{____ ,"field1"->var_, "field2"->var2_, ____}-> {var,var2}, Infinity]
```

The second is replace.

```
dumvar = {"field1", "field2", ..} /. data
```

Comment: By parsing, I mean converting a String (which is a JSON representation of some data) into a list that contains the data itself.